# fstab configuration is ok, but it is diffrent in output of 'df -h'

Tags: centos, disk-usage, fstab

i configure '/etc/fstab' like below:

```
UUID=760f2c21-d558-4456-b938-66f4230ae643 /boot                         xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                                            swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=f9a47631-7115-4e9c-8b5d-bfcf6861446f /dbdata1                      xfs     defaults        1 2
UUID=fad8dbf9-f97a-43c9-8b48-c4ed3ecf11a7 /dbdata2                      xfs     defaults        1 2
```

but when it is not ok in output of 'df -h' command:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   46G  1.8G   45G   4% /
devtmpfs                 2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    2.9G   12M  2.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                 10G   86M   10G   1% /dbdata2
/dev/sdc1                 50G  343M   50G   1% /dbdata1
/dev/sda1               1014M  142M  873M  14% /boot
```

my operating system is centos7.5
it is very important for me that sequence of 'df -h' like '/etc/fstab/' 
please help me ..
thanks

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? Why is the sequence very important?

Comment: because we have some application for monitoring that involves some script to use it.

Comment: and it is important for us , why are the output diffrent ?

Comment: I do not understand why using a script to read these files could be a problem. Anyway, `df -h` lists the mount points in alphabetical order while in the `fstab` file you can (sort of) have the order you want.

Comment: I think that is not true that "df -h lists the mount points in alphabetical". i have this problem just in centos7, in the older version like 6.5 or 6.9... everything that I put in the 'fstab ' i see in 'df -h' in order.@Paradox

Comment: The application or the script should not expect any particular order from the sole `df`. In my Debian `df` preserves order taken from its operands (if submitted). If you need to monitor `/dbdata1` and `/dbdata2` then try to rely on `df -h /dbdata1 /dbdata2`, or just run one `df` per mountpoint. Sorting the output of `df` is also an option.

Comment: each time I reboot the system, the order of 'df -h' has been changed. I have never faced to this problem in the older version. it is not logically that every time I reboot the system I see different result. @Kamil Maciorowski

Comment: So do not trust the order. Provide operands, use `grep`, `awk`, `sort`. I don't think `df` promised fixed order, ever. I *guess* the actual order depends on what kernel says when queried, probably in a fashion near to "first mounted – first listed". Before `systemd` this might be somewhat related to entries in `fstab` because they (or some of them) were read and mounted sequentially. But this was more like a side effect of this sequentiality. Today `systemd` converts `fstab` into native units dynamically at boot and (in general) mounts in parallel.